# Getting the real width of a tableview cell during -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: when there is a section index present

Tags: iphone, uitableview

The proper height for my custom UITableViewCells depends on their width. Unfortunately, it is difficult to know the *actual* content area width of a cell in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, since the only information I have to work with is the tableview. Several factors can change the content width so it is not equal to `tableView.bounds.size.width`; the one I'm struggling with now is the section index. (Another is if the tableview is grouped.)

Is there a good way in general to get the cell content width from just the tableView?

Failing that, is there any way to get the width of the section index, so that I can subtract it from the bounds width? (I don't want to hard code it, since that won't be portable across devices.)

Note: This is not a dup of [Need access to the cell in the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116847/need-access-to-the-cell-in-the-tableviewheightforrowatindexpath) because the solution there is just to use the bounds. Nor is it a dup of [Get tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to happen after tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352801/get-tableviewheightforrowatindexpath-to-happen-after-tableviewcellforrowatinde) since the solution there is to hard code a constant (265.0), which isn't portable across devices.

Comment: Do you mean, you don't want to hard code the section index width, or you don't want to hard code the width of the cell? The former would still be portable across all devices.

Comment: Do you really want to subtract the section index area? I always understood it as being just on top of anything and would only leave the space blank if it really distracts from the contents.

Comment: @Felixs I don't want to hard code the section index width. And in fact, I just discovered that the section index width can change on a single device, depending on what characters are in the section index -- I've now seen it at both 31 and 32. (I know, I know, it's one point, but it's the principle of the thing.)

Comment: @Eiko: The section index area does change the UITableViewCell's contentView.bounds.size. The contentView is the one that I use and track, since it responds properly to editing state, etc.

Comment: Subtracting the section index width from the UITableViewCell *will* be portable across all (apple) devices, +- the aforementioned pixel. Since you cannot directly access the section index as a view object, there is no way to find out its (virtually un-varying) width. Principles are there to help your development, not hinder it.

Comment: Scratch that 31/32 comment -- that inadvertently included some extra padding I had in there. The variation by one point remains true, though.

Comment: @Felixs absolutely. If there's no way, there's no way, and I'll hard code constants. I'd just *rather* not, if there's an option to...which in this case there appears not to be.

Comment: The reason one point matters, though, is for cases in which words will wrap, causing a significant change in the height of the cell -- if I go too low, words get lost. Too high, and there are blank lines.

Comment: But surely you can determine this by using sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: ?

Comment: @Felixs: Sort of. :) See my answer to myself below.

Comment: Ok :) It does seem a tad overkill though

Comment: @Felix understood. :) But without that overkill, I end up with either blank lines, or missing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got working. It's ugly, but it works, at least in all the cases I could find.

```
- (CGFloat)sectionIndexWidthForSectionIndexTitles:(NSArray *)titles {
  UIFont *sectionIndexFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0f];
  CGFloat maxWidth = CGFLOAT_MIN;
  for(NSString *title in titles) {
    CGFloat titleWidth = [title sizeWithFont:sectionIndexFont].width;
    maxWidth = MAX(maxWidth, titleWidth);
  }

  CGFloat sectionIndexWidth = 0.0f;
  NSUInteger maxWidthInt = (int)maxWidth;
  switch(maxWidthInt) {
    case 0:
      sectionIndexWidth = 0.0f;
      break;
    case 11:
      sectionIndexWidth = 30.0f;
      break;
    case 12:
      sectionIndexWidth = 31.0f;
      break;
    case 14:
      sectionIndexWidth = 32.0f;
      break;
    default:
      sectionIndexWidth = 0.0f;
      break;
  }

  return sectionIndexWidth;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to save other people a few hours of work....I laboriously tested various fonts and sizes and margins, comparing them to a UIView hierarchy dump of an actual table view with an index, to arrive at this method which will return the width of a table index, so that the bounds of the table view cell content can be calculated as table_width - index_width. I will point out that there is often another 20 pixel right-side amount reserved for an accessory view.

I also discovered that the cell.contentView.bounds is NOT correctly set until AFTER cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell methods are called, so trying to grab the value during those calls is doomed to fail. It is set correctly by the time viewDidAppear is called.

I have no idea how to calculate the index width if the device language is set for a non-English alphabet.

```
- (CGFloat) getMaxIndexViewWidth
{
    CGFloat indexMargin = 21.0;   
    NSArray *sectionTitles = [self sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:nil];  //NOTE -- if multiple tables, pass real one in

    CGFloat maxWidth11 = CGFLOAT_MIN;

    for(NSString *title in sectionTitles)
    {
        CGFloat titleWidth11 = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont  fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:11.0f]].width;
        maxWidth11 = MAX(maxWidth11, titleWidth11);     
    }
    return maxWidth11+indexMargin;
}
```

Comment: I should point out one caveat.  If you have a huge number of indexes (greater than 20 something, not sure the exact number) the table index logic coalesces some of the index titles and only shows a dot to represent them.  If the widest title happens to be one of the hidden ones, then the actual width may be different than the value reported by my code, since it doesn't ignore any titles.